# Is it possible to change the background of the entire row in an html table when only one cell is selected in the row with use of css and styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to be able to distinguish the row of the cell which a user has selected in the html table.

Is there a way to do that with Css and styles or do I need to program it with JQuery and JavaScript?

For example the user may click on the BA cell in the first row. After that I want the background of the first row be light blue.

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD6ME.png)

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');
$('.table-add').click(function() {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});
$('.table-remove').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});
$('.table-up').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return;
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});
$('.table-down').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;
$BTN.click(function() {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function() {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();
    });
    data.push(h);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500');
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #080808;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@import "compass/css3";
.table-editable {
  position: relative;
  .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

table {
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

.table-up {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
  &:hover {
    color: #0b0;
  }
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> JavaScript editable table </title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1> JavaScript Editable Table </h1>
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th> Name</th>
          <th> Roll No </th>
          <th> Class </th>
          <th> Marks </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> Ram </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 1 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 48 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> Rama </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 10 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BSC </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 40 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> sham </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 8 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BCA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 34 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> shama </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 3 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BCA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 30 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be possible using :has selector, but I need to see your code in order to give you the best possible advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Yes, that can be done.

Comment: you can use the `focus-within` pseudo-class. like this: `tr:focus-within{background: aqua;}`

Comment: You could perhaps use the new `:has` selector, although it isn't widely supported. Yet.

Comment: FYI: [can I use CSS :has](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

Comment: Without the new `:has`, there's not been a css-only way to do this as you can't reference *up*.   They'll be a lot of similar SO questions that state the same.   `:has` changes this, so those questions will be out of date.

Comment: Thank you all, yes with use of :has , I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following code in the style ,with use of has, the selected row would be shown in different color. There is no need for having jquery or javascript code.

```
tr:has(td:focus-visible) {
 background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Comment: :has works ok on most of the main browsers, but on Firefox the user has to enable it first so use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

jquery implement a has selector that you select all parent that has a specific child attribute

```
$('td[contenteditable="true"]').click(function() {
  $( "tr" ).has('td[contenteditable="true"]').removeClass('selected');
  $( "tr" ).has('td[contenteditable="true"]:focus').addClass('selected');
});
```

the selector to select the td that have the focus is `td[contenteditable="true"]:focus`

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');
$('.table-add').click(function() {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});
$('.table-remove').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});
$('.table-up').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return;
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});
$('.table-down').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;
$BTN.click(function() {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function() {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();
    });
    data.push(h);
  });
});


$('td[contenteditable="true"]').click(function() {
  $( "tr" ).has('td[contenteditable="true"]').removeClass('selected');
  $( "tr" ).has('td[contenteditable="true"]:focus').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500');
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #080808;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red !important;
}

th {
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-editable {
  position: relative;
  .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

table {
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto;
}


td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

.table-up {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
  &:hover {
    color: #0b0;
  }
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> JavaScript editable table </title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1> JavaScript Editable Table </h1>
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th> Name</th>
          <th> Roll No </th>
          <th> Class </th>
          <th> Marks </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> Ram </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 1 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 48 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> Rama </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 10 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BSC </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 40 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> sham </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 8 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BCA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 34 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"> shama </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 3 </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> BCA </td>
          <td contenteditable="true"> 30 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was helpful. I could finally find a solution ,which I added in the thread, only with use of css and styles.